Mesh from masked material
is there a way to convert a mesh with a masked material to fully opaque mesh? That is, generating holes where the mask is 0.

Could you apply the mask modifier?

Hello what do you call "masked material", could you please give details?

@moonboots I mean a material in which the alpha channel describes transparency, rather than translucency. For example, any value less than 0.1 is fully transparent; any above is opaque.

If you have an alpha channel, just color ramp it in shade nodes

@DanielMöller unfortunately, I'm too new to blender to know how this will convert a material to geometry. Could you share an example/instructions?

Nothing converts a material to geometry. The most you can do is have invisible geometry. But you have to ask your question properly, we have no idea about what you have and how you have it.

@DanielMöller to give more context - I wish to convert leaf cards into geometry.

We still have no idea of what you have and how you have it.

@DanielMöller ok, let me give an example - I have a quad with a texture like this one: https://www.textures.com/system/gallery/photos/Nature/Leaves/109758/Leaves0158_1_350.jpg - I would like to convert that quad into a geometry in the shape of the leaf.

If it doesn't need to be strictly "geometry", you can easily make materials invisible with "alpha".
Add a plane, add the texture and connect alpha:


If you do mean geometry, this is a naive approach that gives you a pixelated square mesh, starting from a plane with geometry nodes:

You might find it useful to combine both approaches, you can have a rough geometry with bigger pixels (less subdivision) and yet use the image transparency to make the borders look high quality.
You might need to use "faces" instead of "points" in the "separate" node, so you can get the stem with low quality mesh.

That's what I have now and that's exactly what I want to avoid :) I need actual geometry.

@krojew, updated my answer.

Thank you - this looks like what I need.
